# Ошибка при воспроизведении html5 video

Tags: javascript, html5, видео, mobile-web

Возникла некая проблема при загрузке видео html5:
Вставил на страницу 8 видео html5 - тегом, идущих один за другим ( видео не большие, по 15 сек. ). Так вот, в браузере на десктопе все норм грузит, но вот на мобильных устройствах все жутко тормозит, ( появление ошибки "aw snap!", белый экран, вылетает браузер и тд. ) в общем не показывает видео.
Такое ощущение, что не хватает железа. Уменьшил количество видео до 3 - ничего не вылетает.

Отсюда и вопрос, как можно выйти из данной ситуации? Если это реально. Может кто сталкивался?

Вот код вставки видео если что: ( таких 8 штук, только урл разный )

```
<video width="100%" height="auto" controls="true" preload="metadata">
  <source src="visionaire-8.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="visionaire-8.webm" type="video/webm">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Не издеваться над телефоном...

Comment: Можно попробовать удалять те видео, которые не видны и показывать только нужный. Но я в этом не уверен, может только ухудшить ситуацию. Надо пробовать!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вышел из ситуации просто показом видео в попапе, так не происходит инициализация многих плееров одновременно

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю сделать через ajax, т.е. у тебя есть страница с 3 видео, и при скроллинге добавляются новые видео

```
<div class="cat">
<div class="media">
    <script>
        $(".cat").on("touchmove", scrolling);
        var count = 4;
        var begin = 0;
        videoitem();

        function scrolling() {
            videoitem();
        }

        function videoitem() {
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'video.php',
                data: {
                    count: count,
                    begin: begin * count
                },
                success: onAjaxSuccess
            });

            function onAjaxSuccess(data) {
                $(".media").append(data);
            }
            begin++;
        }
    </script>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Точно не помню но у браузеров есть лимит на "preload" видео, соответственно на телефонах он меньше чем на пк.

Как вариант всем поставить вместо `preload="metadata"` =>

`preload="none"` и добавить `poster="src"`

ну или первому оставить `preload="metadata"`, а остальным `none`